# Check SVG with JS dompurify

Tags: javascript, dompurify

I'm using [DomPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) to sanitize SVG code.

It works fine however I would like to show a message if SVG code entered in a textarea is not valid.

I'm trying to compare the SVG code added with the SVG code sanitized. If they are different I will show a message.

```
function validate() {
  if( svgCode.trim() === DOMPurify.sanitize(svgCode).trim() ) {
    console.log('All right!');
  } else {
    console.log('Uuuh-oooh! The SVG code is not valid!');
  }
}

validate();
```

The issue: I keep getting `Uuuh-oooh! The SVG code is not valid!` because dompurify turns closing paths like `/>` into full paths '`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removed` property to check if any sanitization happened or not.

e.g.

```js
  DOMPurify.sanitize('<svg onload=alert(1) />');
  console.log(DOMPurify.removed.length); // 1
  DOMPurify.sanitize('<svg />');
  console.log(DOMPurify.removed.length); // 0
```

https://github.com/is2ei/DOMPurify#okay-makes-sense-lets-move-on

> After sanitizing your markup, you can also have a look at the property DOMPurify.removed and find out, what elements and attributes were thrown out. Please do not use this property for making any security critical decisions. This is just a little helper for curious minds.